# Got stuck with an error. Application exits with following error message in console

Tags: iphone, xcode

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

This error is seen only when running application in iPhone/iPad device and not on simulator.
Any help?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of errors, I have only the reboot/cleanup suggestion:

- remove the application from the device
- reboot the device
- clean the project
- close Xcode
- reopen Xcode
- rebuild
- redeploy